# Нужна ли запятая? или возможна?

Tags: пунктуация

> Мой сосед, такой надоедливый.

Нужна ли запятая? или  возможна? или возможны другие знаки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Классический вариант - это отсутствие знаков, так как именная часть сказуемого выражена прилагательным. В качестве авторского знака возможно тире, при этом будет меняться интонация: после "мой сосед" делается пауза и подлежащее выделяется тоническим ударением. Такая интонация передает повышенную экспрессию и эмоциональность сообщения.
Местоимение ТАКОЙ  перед прилагательным имеет усилительное значение.

Answer (score 0):

> ...или возможны другие знаки?

Возможны и другие — в таком, к примеру, контексте:

*— Кто это такой?*

*— Мой сосед. Такой надоедливый!*